# Black screen with text after upgrading ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade

I thought that I could ask this since I haven't seen anything related to my problem.

I tried to upgrade ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 using this method [ http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04 ]. Ubuntu downloaded everything and installed. When the system asked to be restarted, I clicked the button. The system boots up again and then, I get a black screen with this text:

```
mount: mounting /dev/loopv on /root failed: Invalid argument

mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory

mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory

mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.


BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

I dunno what it means, I dunno if ubuntu 14.04 installed properly or not. Or, If I have to put some code there to make ubuntu work again. But that's it. How can I make Ubuntu work again? Is it possible from this black screen?

Thanks guys for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for complaining, but you should've just upgraded through the Software Updater. The way you upgraded is pretty unstable. If you have ANY backups, just restore from there, and upgrade Ubuntu through the Software Updater.